# How to display only one figure in a loop Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to display a figure in a loop in Matlab. I'm using this code as a simple example of mine

```
for i=1:10

figure('renderer','zbuffer')

end
```

but the problem is that in every iteration a new figure is created for example, if i have 10 iterations then 10 figures will appear, which I don't want, I want only one figure to appear in all the iterations as `figure 1`where in each iteration the old data is replaced by the new ones. So, if anyone could advise how to do this?

Comment: Can you show some code? It might be easier to help.

Comment: thanks Dinesh! I've updated it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the loop, open the figure with

```
h=figure(1)
```

and then set the renderer with

```
set(h,'renderer','zbuffer')
```

then start the loop. I can't see why you would need to set the renderer every iteration. If you do want to set the renderer at each iteration, then you can just put the `set(h,'renderer','zbuffer)` line inside the loop to replace your `figure('renderer','zbuffer')`.

Edited to add: The reason it was opening a new figure each time for you was that `figure('renderer','zbuffer')` opens a new figure window. To change the properties of an already-opened figure window you must use `set`.